# How can I force Visual Studio to trust all projects in a solution?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a solution for Orchard CMS, which, when I first opened it, prompted me asking whether to trust projects from an external source. I unchecked the box for "Ask for every project in the solution", and it opened fine. Now, I used a code generation tool to add a project to the solution while it was open. VS then detected a change, and prompted me to reload the solution. After reloading, I see most - save 1 or 2 out of a great many - projects failed to load. When I click on an individual project and reload that, I get asked whether I trust it again. When I click OK, the project loads fine. Only issue is I don't want to go and manually reload every project. I tried closing the solution and opening it again, but then most projects still fail to load.

Comment: What happens if you select all of the currently unloaded projects, right click, and reload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reload multiple projects at once:  simply select multiple projects in the Solution Explorer (e.g. via Ctrl+Click or Shift+Click), right-click the selection, and choose Reload Project.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this type of issue by following these instructions from the Visual Studio documentation.

[Configure trust settings for files and folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/trust-settings?view=vs-2019#add-trusted-paths)

Basically:

1. Open Tools > Options > Trust Settings and select the Configure Trust Settings link in the right-hand pane.
2. Click Add in the Trust Settings dialog, and then select File or Folder.
3. Navigate to and select the file or folder you want to add to the trusted list.